# window.pageYOffset is always returning 0. (But only on a windows machine returns correct number on Mac)

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm working on a sticky header function that will make my header and weekday list stick to the top of the page. Pretty much the same as the one found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sticky_header.asp). The following code works fine on a Mac however it becomes problematic on a Windows computer when window.pageYoffset always returns 0. Any suggestions on why this is would be helpful.

Note: my body tag does not have a height property and is not set to overflow: hidden.

```
 window.onscroll = function() {respiteStickyFunction()};

              // Get the header
              var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
              var weekdayHeader = document.getElementsByClassName("fc-head")[0];
                
              // Get the offset position of the navbar
              var sticky = header.offsetTop;
              
              // Add the sticky class to the header when you reach its scroll position. Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
              function respiteStickyFunction() {
                
                console.log(sticky, window.pageYOffset )

                if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
                  header.classList.add("sticky");
                  weekdayHeader.classList.add("sticky-weekdays");
                } else {
                  header.classList.remove("sticky");
                  weekdayHeader.classList.remove("sticky-weekdays");
                }
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a snippet and it works for me in Chrome/Windows 10. "works" = your code is logging non-zero values for the pageYOffset.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {respiteStickyFunction()};

              // Get the header
              var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
              var weekdayHeader = document.getElementsByClassName("fc-head")[0];
                
              // Get the offset position of the navbar
              var sticky = header.offsetTop;
              
              // Add the sticky class to the header when you reach its scroll position. Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
              function respiteStickyFunction() {
                
                console.log(sticky, window.pageYOffset )

                if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
                  header.classList.add("sticky");
                  weekdayHeader.classList.add("sticky-weekdays");
                } else {
                  header.classList.remove("sticky");
                  weekdayHeader.classList.remove("sticky-weekdays");
                }
              }
```

```html
<h id="myHeader"></h>
<p>sample text</p>
<p class="fc-head">sample text</p>
<p>sample text</p>
<p>sample text</p>
<p>sample text</p>
<p>sample text</p>
<p>sample text</p>
<p>sample text</p>
<p>sample text</p>
<p>sample text</p>
<p>sample text</p>
<p>sample text x</p>
<p>sample text</p>
<p>sample text</p>
<p>sample text</p>
<p>sample text</p>
<p>sample text</p>
<p>sample text</p>
<p>sample text</p>
<p>sample text</p>
<p>sample text</p>
<p>sample text</p>
```